# why i can not get 200 response for POST and PUT request?

Tags: spring-boot

I have utilized the RouterFunction feature in my Spring Boot web application. However, when I use Postman to test POST and PUT requests, I encounter a 404 error. (GET and DELETE requests, on the other hand, are accessible without any issues.)
here is my springboot config class:

```
@Configuration
public class WebFunctionConfig {
    private static final RequestPredicate ACCEPT_JSON = accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    @Bean
    public RouterFunction<ServerResponse> userRoute(UserBizHandler userHandler){
        return RouterFunctions.route()
                .GET("/user/{id}", accept(MediaType.ALL),userHandler::getUser)
                .GET("/users",userHandler::getUsers)
                .POST("/user", ACCEPT_JSON,userHandler::addUser)
                .PUT("/user/{id}", ACCEPT_JSON,userHandler::updateUser)
                .DELETE("/user/{id}",userHandler::deleteUser)
                .build();

    }
}
```

here is my handler class:

```
@Service
@Slf4j
public class UserBizHandler {
    public ServerResponse getUser(ServerRequest request){
        log.info("get user info");
        Person person = new Person("bob", "22@11.com", 20);
        return ServerResponse.ok().body(person);
    }
    public ServerResponse getUsers(ServerRequest request){
        log.info("get all users' info");
        List<Person> personList = Arrays.asList(new Person("bob", "22@11.com", 20), new Person("Tom", "22@11.com", 30));
        return ServerResponse.ok().body(personList);
    }
    public ServerResponse addUser(ServerRequest request){
        log.info("add user info");
        return ServerResponse.ok().build();
    }
    public ServerResponse updateUser(ServerRequest request){
        log.info("update user info ");
        return ServerResponse.ok().build();
    }
    public ServerResponse deleteUser(ServerRequest request){
        log.info("delete user info ");
        return ServerResponse.ok().build();
    }


}
```

here is my current operation for **post** and **put** request:
[image]

[image]
i utilize **postman **as test tool.

1. i changed the method to post and put .
2. i add **map'content-type:application/json'** to **Headers**.
3. I add  **"{
   "username": "张三",
   "email": "22@11.com",
   "age": 20
   }"** to request **body**
   but i got 404 error :

```
<Map>
    <timestamp>2024-02-24T06:22:34.393+00:00</timestamp>
    <status>404</status>
    <error>Not Found</error>
    <path>/user/1</path>
</Map>
```

why i encountered it ?